# Quick way to prove uniqueness of inverses in a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Is the following reasoning valid?

Theorem: The inverses in a vector space are unique.

Proof: Let $V$ be a vector space. Then $(V, +)$ is an abelian group, and since group inverses are unique, every vector $v \in V$ has a unique inverse $v^{-1} = -v$.

Of course, the direct way of proving it is straightforward, so I'm just wondering if this  "abstract nonsense" style of approach is just as rigorous. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you know the vectors are an Abelian group, you're done. But before you prove that, *how do you know*? You are assuming the thing you are required to prove. Of course if you define a vector space as an Abelian group along with a field of scalars, your argument is ok. But most elementary definitions of vector spaces don't say that.

Comment: The question came up for me from Proposition 2 of section 2 of this sheet from UC Davis: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Le-Vector_Spaces#:~:text=Every%20vector%20space%20has%20a,additive%20identities%200%20and%200%E2%80%B2.&text=Suppose%20w%20and%20w%E2%80%B2%20are,v%20%2B%20w%E2%80%B2%20%3D%200. (cont)

Comment: (cont) So V being a vector space is already established, although now that you mention it, it probably doesn't make sense to bother proving it. OTOH, Hoffman Kunze proves that $c 0 = 0$, which is still fairly trivial but at least a bit more interesting since it involves the interaction of scalars with vectors.

Comment: Your link gives the usual definition, which does not say anything about Abelian groups or their properties. My comment applies. Given the axioms, how do you know additive inverses are unique? You have to prove it.

Comment: The question isn’t whether you already know that $V$ is a vector space or not. The question is how “vector space” is defined. If you define a vector space by saying “It has an operation $+$ which makes it an abelian group, and `blah`”, then your argument works (provided you already proved that inverses are unique in abelian groups). But most linear algebra texts, *and this handout*, does not say **that**. Instead it gives you a bunch of axioms that the set and operations satisfy, and you must justify your conclusion invoking *those* axiomns, not something else.

Answer (score 1):

For this to be “rigorous” you need to:

1. Prove that in an abelian group, inverses are unique (this is not an explicit part of the definition of abelian group, so it has to be established).
2. Prove that the underlying additive structure of a vector space makes its into an abelian group (this is not part of the usual explicit definition of a vector space, so it must be proven).

And in order to do 1, you have to do essentially what you do in a vector space without any reference to abelian groups: you first prove the identity is unique, then you prove inverses are unique.

So your proposal isn’t *really* “abstract nonsense”, and moreover requires you do to way more than what the direct proof asks to do, by requiring you to establish a more general proposition (something for all abelian groups/modules), and then by establishing that your object is also one of the more general class of objects.